# Bug in MeshRegion with PlotRange?

Tags: graphics, mesh

Consider the simple following example:

```
MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
  {Triangle[{1, 2, 3}], Triangle[{1, 2, 4}], Triangle[{1, 2, 5}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-5, 5}}]
```

It returns this wrong image:

[image]

and when I click on the image I get the correct image (with the correct `PlotRange`):

[image]

What's happening?

Comment: I think the output is shrink wrapped. `Show[mesh, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}]` seems to fix things.

Comment: @ChipHurst Perfect. Maybe you could write an answer, as that solves my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the output is shrink wrapped. This fixes things:

```
mesh = MeshRegion[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
  {Triangle[{1, 2, 3}], Triangle[{1, 2, 4}], Triangle[{1, 2, 5}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-5, 5}}
];

Show[mesh, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> False}]
```

[image]